# Integrate or enable ElasticSearch with Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, elasticsearch, integration

I am using Magento's latest community version **Magento 2.3.3**. I am very new to ElasticSearch. I want to integrate Elasticsearch with Magento, So I took reference from here https://www.tigren.com/magento-2-elasticsearch/ and install Elasticsearch on the localhost.

[image]

[image]

According to my screenshots, I think, I set up elasticsearch successfully on my local machine but unfortunately, I can't see better search result on the frontend (I mean quick result). On the frontend side, it still takes lots of time for showing results.

Any idea where I am wrong?

and How can I check on frontend elastic search working or not?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check the ElasticSearch on the storefront working or not.
Below plugin may help you.

**di.xml**

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="\Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\ResponseFactory">
      <plugin name="check_es_call" type="\Check\Es\Plugin\ESResponseCheck" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**ESResponseCheck.php**

```
<?php
namespace Check\Es\Plugin;

use Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;


class ESResponseCheck
{

    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger        
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;

    }

    public function beforeCreate(\Magento\Elasticsearch\SearchAdapter\ResponseFactory $subject, $result)
    {
       if(!is_array($result) || empty($result)) return false;
       foreach ($result['documents'] as $rawDocument) {
            $this->logger->debug('ELASTIC_SEARCH_DEBUG_CODE',$rawDocument);   
       }            

    }       

}
```

You can also install Kibana or Logstash monitoring tool for ElasticSearch.

Comment: I used your above code and get the below logs:
[2019-12-26 15:49:57] main.DEBUG: ELASTIC_SEARCH_DEBUG_CODE {"_index":"magento2_product_1_v5","_type":"document","_id":"180","_score":51.224762} []
[2019-12-26 15:49:57] main.DEBUG: ELASTIC_SEARCH_DEBUG_CODE {"_index":"magento2_product_1_v5","_type":"document","_id":"84","_score":44.61884} []
[2019-12-26 15:49:57] main.DEBUG: ELASTIC_SEARCH_DEBUG_CODE {"_index":"magento2_product_1_v5","_type":"document","_id":"260","_score":44.060844} []

Is ElasticSarch working on my store?

Comment: yes, absolutely it is working.. That means ElasticSearch is working on the storefront.

Comment: thanks for the help. Happy Coding...!!!