# Rejecting mapping update to [magento2_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type

Tags: magento2, php, elasticsearch, magento2.4.3

I've recently upgraded my Magento 2 store from version 2.4.1 to 2.4.3.

However, I'm encountering issues when running the catalog search, And I'm receiving the following error message:

> main.CRITICAL:
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
> mapping update to [magento2_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would
> have more than 1 type: [_doc,
> document]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
> mapping update to [magento2_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would
> have more than 1 type: [_doc, document]"},"status":400}
> {"exception":"[object]
> (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\BadRequest400Exception(code: 400):
> {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
> mapping update to [magento2_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would
> have more than 1 type: [_doc,
> document]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting
> mapping update to [magento2_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would
> have more than 1 type: [_doc, document]"},"status":400} at
> /var/www/html/vendor/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/src/Elasticsearch/Connections/Connection.php:675)"}
> []

I've consulted the official documentation, And it indicates that Magento 2.4.3 is compatible with Elasticsearch version 7.10. I'm using Elasticsearch 7.10 with Magento 2.4.3.

Despite this, I'm facing indexing issues.

Could you please provide guidance/solution on how to resolve this issue?

Your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you please try to change the indexer name in the elastic search setting then try?

Comment: I tried but it's not work. The error is same

Comment: Were you using elasticsearch 6.x during your previous installation?

Comment: Please see my reply

Comment: just check your jdk version with respect to that elasticsearch version

Comment: Can you try this : 

    curl -X GET "http://your_elasticsearch_server:9200/your_index_name/_mapping" to check the mapping

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Elasticsearch REST API for this like **Kibana** to inspect your indexes.

Then you can check the version in the Elasticsearchtemplate . This problem is due to Index Template issue in Elasticsearch you can follow the below link to update the indexes :

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/rejecting-mapping-update-to-xxx-as-the-final-mapping-would-have-more-than-1-type-doc-xxx/298839/11

Answer (score 0):

> **Try This**

**You can check this solution where you need to update two settings in your elasticsearch.**

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{ "transient": { "cluster.routing.allocation.disk.threshold_enabled": false } }'


curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:9200/_all/_settings -d '{"index.blocks.read_only_allow_delete": null}'
```

For More: https://www.appsloveworld.com/magentocdng/219/elasticsearch-badrequest400exception-error-main-critical-quoterrorquot?expand_article=1

**Other Solutions**

1. [Magento 2.4 Elastic search error: Text fields are not optimised for operations](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341417/magento-2-4-elastic-search-error-text-fields-are-not-optimised-for-operations)
2. [Magento 2.x Elasticsearch Category Products Not Showing](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/322516/magento-2-x-elasticsearch-category-products-not-showing?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Thanks for helping, could you please describe how to change prefix for each store? The field "Elasticsearch Index Prefix" is available only when the Scope is "default config"
When I switch to Store (I have to 4) the field is not available at all.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: @Msquare it is not correct. Elasticsearch prefix is a global scope setting. It cannot be set different for each store.

Comment: @AfreenSheikh I updated the answer. Thanks for your kind information.

Comment: Thank for helping guys, it's not working. When i run first command I get following info `{"acknowledged":true,"persistent":{},"transient":{"cluster":{"routing":{"allocation":{"disk":{"threshold_enabled":"false"}}}}}}` and the second command i get `{"acknowledged":true}`. But when I run indexer error is still same

Comment: Should I restart my ES cluster?

Comment: Here is the full errors: `Catalog Search index process error during indexation process:
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [eshop_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, document]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [eshop_product_1_v2] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [_doc, document]"},"status":400}`

Answer (score 0):

I think in your case it's just a configuration issue as during upgrade sometimes search engine doesn't update on all places required and sometimes gets locked up in environment variables as well.

Run following command to confirm whether your search engine is set to elasticsearch7

```
php bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine
```

If it is elasticsearch6 or something else or even if it is elasticsearch 7, run following command

```
php bin/magento --lock-env config:set  catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
```

Above command will also set the elasticsearch version in env as well.

Try above things and if it doesn't work I have a few more ideas which may be causing this issue.

Comment: Result is same. I run above command and run `bin/magento setup:di:compile`, restart apache and result is same.

Comment: Did you get elasticsearch7 when youi ran config:show command?

Comment: Yes it was ES 7.